# NSArray Data to Both UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ipad, uitableview, nsmutablearray, singleton, uipopovercontroller

I have an NSMutableArray I build with the below code

```
//Question Array Setup and Alloc
    stratToolsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:countButton,@"count",camerButton,@"camera",videoButton,@"video",textButton,@"text",probeButton,@"probe", nil];
    stratTools = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Tools",stratToolsDict, nil];
    stratObjectsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:stratTools,@"Strat1",stratTools,@"Strat2",stratTools,@"Strat3",stratTools,@"Strat4", nil];
    stratObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Strategies:",stratObjectsDict,nil];
    QuestionDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:stratObjects,@"Question 1?",stratObjects,@"Question 2?",stratObjects,@"Question 3?",stratObjects,@"Question 4?",stratObjects,@"Question 5?", nil];


    //add strategys to questions
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        //Send Var to STVar
        [[STVars myMutableArray]addObject:QuestionDict];
    }
```

In the `For` Loop you will see "[STVars myMutableArray]" this is a singleton method used in storing the Question Array.

My problem lies in the fact that i have a UIPopOverController that has a UITableView which needs to be able to load all the questions titles.....ex(@"Question 1", @"Question 2").
They should then be populated as the datasource for the UITableView in the UIPopOverController.

As well in the class where i initialize the Question Array there is a UICollectionView which also needs to grab all the Strategies from the Question Array for the Question Clicked from the UIPopOverController.

Here is the UIPopOverController Accessing the Singleton Array which does have Data.
When i attach the Array and try to load the cells i get a "SIGABRT" error.....(Hate that One.)

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    if ([super initWithStyle:style] != nil) {

        //Log test
        NSLog(@"QuestionList init method from STVars: %@",[STVars myMutableArray]);
        QuestionsList = [STVars myMutableArray];
```

You can see that i check with NSLog first to make sure the Data is in the Array in the Singleton class. Then i assign the array to another NSMutableArray *QuestionsList.

When i assign it to the UITableView it never shows up.

Sizing the UIPopOvercontroller:

```
//Make row selections persist.
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        //Calculate how tall the view should be by multiplying
        //the individual row height by the total number of rows.
        NSInteger rowsCount = [QuestionsList count];
        NSInteger singleRowHeight = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView
                                               heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        NSInteger totalRowsHeight = rowsCount * singleRowHeight;

        //Calculate how wide the view should be by finding how
        //wide each string is expected to be
        CGFloat largestLabelWidth = 0;
        for (NSString *questionName in QuestionsList) {
            //Checks size of text using the default font for UITableViewCell's textLabel.
            CGSize labelSize = [questionName sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
            if (labelSize.width > largestLabelWidth) {
                largestLabelWidth = labelSize.width;
            }
        }

        //Add a little padding to the width
        CGFloat popoverWidth = largestLabelWidth + 100;

        //Set the property to tell the popover container how big this view will be.
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(popoverWidth, totalRowsHeight);
```

Table Cells Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [QuestionsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I can not seem to get these Cells to populate any of the Questions from the Array.
A nice simple explanation as to why it may not be showing up would be really nice.
I have been developing for a few days straight and think it could be something simple but cant catch it....any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to init questions list, i know you can assign data like this and not get a error until the table actually looks for a count or tries to create cells. Try  QuestionsList = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[STVars myMutableArray],nil];

Comment: @rezand i tried this and i get SIGABRT error? If i open a chat would you help me solve this issue?

Comment: @rezand http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32721/questions-nsarray-singleton-to-uipopovercontrollers-uitableview